# how to enforce "just commit after test"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, methodology

The world of writing test is beautiful. But the problem is that with the time, some developers just "forget" (read: don't want, believe that its not necessary) to run all the test cases before the next commit and update test cases as the components are being updated.

using GIT, does exist a way to enforce "commit is just allowed after that the tests successfully ran" ?

update: i know the pre, post hook, but i look more for solutions, recepts and etc.

Comment: Make them pay each time they break a test with such a commit. Then use that money to buy more coffee for all the other developers ;-)

Comment: sehr gut, sie werden mich lieben :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pre-commit hook on your blessed repository.
Quoting the [Git Community Book's entry on hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html):

> GIT_DIR/hooks/pre-commit
>
> This hook is invoked by 'git-commit', and can be bypassed with --no-verify option. It takes no parameter, and is invoked before obtaining the proposed commit log message and making a commit. Exiting with non-zero status from this script causes the 'git-commit' to abort.

Comment: I actually checked the documentation and the solution was there :-)

Comment: Great! What did you implement?

Comment: ruby script in the pre-commit, for commits in the HEAD. worked great

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a continuous integration server, which does run the tests each time new commits arrive a central repository. While this does not prevent the different developers to skip over the local test part, it can give direct feedback every time such an event occurs and send mails out to the whole team. The rest is how the team deals with persons who constantly breaks some rules.